# Count for a series of dataframe by specific classes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

These two dataframe *c1*, *c2* contain some company and the countries they belong to.

```
## Data of c1: 6 company in 4 countries.
   Country    Company
0   USA    Walmart
1   USA    Apple
2   China  CNPC 
3   China  State_grid 
4   UK     BP 
5   Japan  Toyota    

## Data of c2: 10 company in the same 4 countries.    
   Country    Company
0   USA    Walmart
1   USA    Apple
2   USA    Verizon
3   USA    JP_Morgan
4   China  CNPC 
5   China  China_Bank 
6   UK     BP 
7   Japan  Toyota
8   Japan  Honda
9   Japan  Sony
```

We can notice that some company in  *c1* and *c2* are different(eg: Honda), some are same(eg: Walmart).

*My target*

> Combine these two dataframe and summarize the amount of company for each country.

A. For just one dataframe, I can use

```
> c1.Country.value_counts()
output:
USA      2
China    2
UK       1
Japan    1
```

B. For two dataframes which has some same contents, I try to use  `unique` function to remove the repeater.

```
>dc = pd.concat([c1.Company,c2.Company])
>print len(dc)
>print len(dc.unique())

Output:
> 16
> 11
```

How to combine c1 & c2 process together, and filter the repeater?
Then, I can get the statistical result like follows:

```
   Country    Company
0   USA    Walmart
1   USA    Apple
2   USA    Verizon
3   USA    JP_Morgan
4   China  CNPC 
5   China  State_grid 
6   China  China_Bank 
7   UK     BP 
8   Japan  Toyota
9   Japan  Honda
10   Japan  Sony
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) `DataFrames` and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
 c = pd.concat([c1, c2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Country','Company']).reset_index(drop=True)
  Country     Company
0     USA     Walmart
1     USA       Apple
2     USA     Verizon
3     USA   JP_Morgan
4   China        CNPC
5   China  China_Bank
6      UK          BP
7   Japan      Toyota
8   Japan       Honda
9   Japan        Sony

print c.Country.value_counts()
USA      4
China    3
Japan    3
UK       1
Name: Country, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the dataframe has more than two columns, the third column has different values. Can `drop_duplicates()` works?

Comment: You have to use parameter `subset` in  `drop_duplicates `- I add it to answer